# JavaScript Closure

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have a simple question about Javascript Closures:

The following function is given:

```
function outside() {
  var out = 0;
    function inside() {
    out +=1;
    }
  return inside;
} 

var ref = outside();
ref();  
ref();
```

If I call the function 2 times, `out` is equal to 2.

Why is `out` not overwritten by the statement?

```
var out = 0;
```

Comment: I think the best way to understand it is to experience it. Make a test page (or fiddle) with this code, then go through it, step by step, using your browser's debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `var out = 0` is not inside the function returned from `outside()`. It only runs when you call `outside()` not when you call `ref()` (which is the same as `inside()`).

Comment: thanks, i totally missed the return statement of outside()

Answer (score 1):

`outside()` returns `inside`. So `ref = inside`. When you call `ref()`, it's like calling `inside()`.

`inside` has the scope of `outside`, which contains `out`. When you call ref(), it increments the `out` property on the single scope of `outside`.